# Change expired password without "Password Expired dialog box"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I'm logging on my application using Sql Server Database logon account. However, when a user's password is expired, i can only catch the error message using "error:18488" and display a message to user.

When I login using Sql Server Management Studio with an account with expired password, a dialog box requiring me to change password appears.

Is there a way to allow my application to change the expired password with something like T-Sql statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found the solution [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb8k729z.aspx), I used `SqlConnection.ChangePassword()`.

Here's the code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ChangePassword(
        "Data Source=a_server;Initial Catalog=a_database;UID=user;PWD=old_password", 
       "new_password");
    }
}
```

Hope it helps others too. :)

Comment: Sorry, but i have no idea about oracle. I am using `.Net` and 'SQL Server 2008` so I only got the solution from `MSDN`.

Answer (score 2):

You can change a user login using [ALTER LOGIN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189828%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
ALTER LOGIN [userName] WITH PASSWORD=N'StrongPassword'
```

Another option is to use the Stored Procedure [sp_password](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174428%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

```
sp_password [ [ @old = ] 'old_password' , ]
     { [ @new =] 'new_password' }
     [ , [ @loginame = ] 'login' ]
```

**C# code:**

```
private readonly SqlConnection m_oConn = new SqlConnection("ConnectionString");
private readonly SqlCommand m_oCmd;

m_oCmd = new SqlCommand("sp_password", m_oConn) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

m_oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@old", null);
m_oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@new", "newpassword");
m_oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loginame", "username");

var da = new SqlDataAdapter { SelectCommand = m_oCmd };

var ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: I've used `SqlConnection.ChangePassword()` instead as it fits more with in my case. Thanks for your help anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using sqlcmd.exe utility.

```
–> sqlcmd
–> sp_password @new = “newpassword”, @loginame = “sa”
–> go
–> exit
```

Check this link:

[Changing the sa password using sqlcmd](http://cagatayozgur.wordpress.com/2010/03/26/changing-the-sa-password-using-sqlcmd/)

Comment: I've used `SqlConnection.ChangePassword()` instead as it fits more with in my case. Thanks for your help anyway. :)