# How can I change SQL Server login account password on first login via C#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have a SQL Server login that I want to use it for first time, and when I use it I get this error:

> Login failed for user MyUserName.  Reason: The password of the account must be changed.

I can't access SQL Server directly, how can I change password by C# code? I try this code but It returns the same error on `conn.Open();`

Code:

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=[ServerName];
Initial Catalog=[DBName];
User ID=[MyUserName];Password=[MyPassword];");
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("ALTER LOGIN [MyUserName] WITH PASSWORD='NewPass' OLD_PASSWORD='OldPass'", conn);
conn.Open();
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Will the SqlConnection.ChangePassword() method work in this instance. Just a shot in the dark as I have never run across this before. Check this thread. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730409/change-expired-password-without-password-expired-dialog-box